# how to utilize Vmware.vim in my C# program?

Tags: c#, vmware, vcenter

I know this is a super newb question and I am probably going to catch heat for this.

but I am new to coding in C#, I have been a systems engineer for a while now, and have great knowledge on using Vsphere CLI and Powershell to do my tasks.

however I am wanting to learn more programing and build something for VMware to make my life easier, from looking stuff up I see that I can call VMware.vim but I need to add it as a project reference.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do exactly that, it is not in the Nuget repo.
and they said I can browse my Pc and add it as a refernce, but I cannot find where to download that .dll from.

thank you to anybody that would be willing to tell me where to download the Vmware.vim.dll from. or any help at all.

looked in Nuget repo.

tried downloading the VMware-vSphere-SDK-8.0.0-20566232, but was unable to add anything as reference.

Comment: "From looking stuff up"... can you share the links you've already read which led you to the conclusion that you need to add a reference to vmware.vim please? I'm approaching this from the opposite direction to you, I'm an experienced C# developer but I don't know the first thing about administering VMWare, and I suspect many members of the SO community who might be able to help answer this question are in the same position, so if you can share what you've already read, that might just give us the right search terms to work out how to answer your question.